# How to logout with flutter_appauth?

Tags: flutter, authentication, openid-connect

I need to logout from [flutter_appauth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth) with a button press in flutter;

This package doesn't have any logout method.

This is my get token code:

```
appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(AuthorizationTokenRequest(
                clientID, redirectUrl,
                discoveryUrl: discoveryUrl,
                scopes: scopes,
                clientSecret: clientSecret
```

Comment: Why you use this package ,when there developer removed this repo from his github.

Comment: @MohammadMirshahbazi I am using the flutter_appauth. The url fixed in the question.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth

Comment: before you edit this link we see [https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_auth/install](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_auth/install)

Comment: @MohammadMirshahbaziI know and it was my mistake. I have logout problem with flutter_appauth package

Comment: Ok bro, i figure out, wait i solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

In that package, didn't any solution for this, but this problem solve with two way :

1. It's your browser so you can clear the browser's cache :)
2. When you call method for authorizing and exchanges code, there is needed to add an additional parameter called "promptValues" with 'login' value. In this way, every time the login is made there is no value in the cache and it always asks for a new login.

do this :

```
final AuthorizationTokenResponse result =
    await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
      AuthorizationTokenRequest(
        your_client_id,
        your_localhost,
        promptValues: ['login'],
        discoveryUrl:
        your_discovery_url,
        scopes: [your_scopes],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I just need a function to logout.
It should not request login info in every login!

Comment: No method exist for logout as far as I realized, but with solution you can clean the cache every time you login, so you are logout because of your cache is clean , try it please it's work.

Comment: How can I clear the cache? The flutter_appauth uses it's built in webview and I can't access to it.
I also delete the getTemporaryDirectory dir, but nothing works.

Comment: Do you store the refresh token somewhere in your case so that you can keep your user signed it?

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 main options here, and as a first step I would see if you can make the first option work, in line with Mohammad's comment:

**OPTION 1: SIMPLE LOGOUT**

Just remove any stored tokens from your app. The problem with this is that it does not remove the Authorization Server Session Cookie. So by default you cannot force another login prompt, eg to sign in as a new user. One way around this is to send **prompt=login** as a parameter when performing the login redirect.

**OPTION 2: FULL LOGOUT**

A full logout involves both of these actions and may require you to dig into AppAuth internals:

- Remove stored tokens from your app
- Redirect to remove the Authorization Server session cookie, via an End Session Request

Here is some [sample Android code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authsamples/basicmobileapp/plumbing/oauth/AuthenticatorImpl.kt) to spin up a Chrome Custom Tab for a logout redirect.

There are other potential issues, such as intermittent Chrome white screens that fail to return to the app after logout, due to a missing user gesture.

**FURTHER INFO**

My blog posts have some further details on AppAuth integration, along with code samples you can run, in case any of this is useful. I am using AppAuth libraries directly from Kotlin / Swift, whereas you need to deal with an additional layer of the Flutter Plugin:

- [Android AppAuth Advanced Sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/)
- [iOS AppAuth Advanced Sample](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/ios-code-sample-overview/)

Answer (score 3):

I created a method that take care of logging out the user by ending the session like that:

```
Future<bool> endSession(String idToken) async {
    //work like logout method
    try {
      await appAuth.endSession(EndSessionRequest(
          idTokenHint: idToken,
          issuer: _issuer,
          postLogoutRedirectUrl: _redirectUrl,
          allowInsecureConnections: _allowInsecureConnections));
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

- If you're using keycloak then `_issuer` will be something like that `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/REALM-NAME`
- `idToken` is what you received after login (inside `AuthorizationTokenResponse`)

Answer (score -2):

**2021 Update:**
Just open the logout page with [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) like this:

```
  if (await canLaunch(logoutUrl)) {
    await launch(logoutUrl);
  }
```

- Remember: You have to redirect to the custom scheme (which you added in build.gradle file) after the logout process.

---

I solved the logout problem with a trick!
I open the browser with a logout link. Then redirect to **[custom_url]**. And get back to the app with an AppLink.

This is how I logout:

1. Follow [this tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app) to create a KeyStore for your app
2. Get the **Certificate fingerprints, SHA256** from the **[generated key].jks** with this command:

> keytool -list -v -keystore [generated key].jks

3. Create an assetlinks.json file with this content:

```
    [
      {
        "relation": [
          "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
        ],
        "target": {
          "namespace": "android_app",
          "package_name": "[app.package.name]",
          "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
            "The Certificate fingerprints, SHA256 created in step 2."
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

and put it on the

> https://**[custom_url]**/.well-known/assetlinks.json

4. Add an intent filter in manifest like this:

```html
<application ...>
  <activity ...>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

      <data 
         android:host="[custom_url]"
         android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

5. And finally, this is the logout function:

```
      Future logout() async {
        if (await canLaunch(_logoutUrl))
          await launch(_logoutUrl);
      }
```